# fb_exchange_token parameter not specified

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I cannot find any documentation on this.

Here is my code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '000000000000000',
  'app_secret' => '00000000000000000000000000000',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
  'persistent_data_hander' => 'session'
]);
$redirect = 'http://www.domain.com/loggedin.php';
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

if (isset($_COOKIE['LOGIN'])){
  header("Location: http://www.domain.com/loggedin.php");
  die();
}else{
        $permissions  = ['user_birthday, user_location'];
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect,$permissions);

?>

<a href="<?php echo "".$loginUrl; } ?>"><img src="assets/img/fbloginbutton.png"></a>
```

**loggedin.php**

```
<?php

//debug
//debug
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//debug
//debug

session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '00000000000000000',
  'app_secret' => '000000000000000000000000000000000',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
  'persistent_data_hander' => 'session'
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

if (isset($_SESSION['fb_a_token']))
{
  $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['fb_a_token']);
}
else
{
  try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($longLivedAccessToken);
    $_SESSION['fb_a_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    //header("Location: http://www.domain.com");
    die();
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com");
    die();
  } catch(Exception $e){
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com");
    die();
  }
}

$accessToken = $_SESSION['fb_a_token'];
$request_parm = '/me?fields=name,gender,age_range,birthday,location';
try {
        $response = $fb->get($request_parm);
        $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
}catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        //echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        header("Location: http://www.domain.com");
        die();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        //echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        header("Location: http://www.domain.com");
        die();
} catch(Exception $e){
        header("Location: http://www.domain.com");
        die();
}

setcookie('LOGIN', 'yes', time() + 9600);

$image = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userNode->getId().'/picture?width=200';

$birthday = $userNode->getProperty('birthday');
$year = (int) $birthday->format('Y');
$curryear = (int) date("Y");
$userage = $curryear - $year;

$gender = $userNode->getProperty('gender');
if ($gender == null) {
        $gender = "other";
}

    ?>

<h3>First name: <?php echo "".$userNode->getName();                     ?>      </h3>
                                        <h3>Age:        <?php echo "".$userage;                                ?>       </h3>
                                        <h3>Gender:     <?php echo "".$gender;                           ?>     </h3>
                                        <h3>Location:   <?php echo "".$userNode->getProperty('location')['name'];          ?>   </h3>
```

I want to know what fb_exchange_token does and how to deal with it.

Replacting my error:

1. delete all cache
2. login and get redirected successfully
3. close browser without deleting cache
4. open browser again at loggedin.php and get this error: **Graph returned an error: fb_exchange_token parameter not specified** which is fired from the very first try-catch in loggedin.php.

Due to shoddy documentation I cannot find anything on fb_exchange_token on the Facebook's website nor elsewhere.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It’s a parameter used in the process of extending access tokens, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension Looks like you don’t have a valid access token at this point, so you can not get a long lived one either.

Comment: @CBroe but I'm logged in. If I refresh the page loggedin.php it seems like I successfully get the user data from Facebook. It's only when I close the browser that things stop working (despite the cookies being there still). I don't have a clue how to fix this.

Comment: @CBroe I checked using the FB debugging tool and you're right. I only get a short lived access token. I still don't know why my code is not working. `$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);`

Comment: `$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();` – that’s the problem. You are using the RedirectHelper, and that expects a `code` parameter to be present in the URL, to exchange for a short-lived access token. `code` doesn’t exist, therefor you get no access token from this method call, and therefor you don’t have an access token to extend in the next step. You need to implement some sort of check if you still have a valid access token/logged-in user, and _not_ use the redirecthelper in that case.